# Exception with WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("urlAddress")

Tags: c#, xml, exception, webconfigurationmanager

I am very new to working with XML. I've been weeding my way through debugging a project that was handed to me, but have run into quite a wall.

My code:

```
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("ToPost.xml");

    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("eclRequest xmlns='" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("urlAddress") + "'");
    .....
```

But the WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("urlAddress") is giving me the following Exception:

> Invalid name character in 'eclRequest xmlns='''. The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.

I was wondering what exactly this Get() statement is accessing, and what could be causing the Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exception of `AppSettings.Get` but of `xmlWriter.WriteStartElement`, which has signature:

```
public void WriteStartElement(
    string localName
)
```

and hence, `localName` is just name of start XML tag, cannot contain space (`' '`). But there are [other overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteStartElement(v=vs.110).aspx), you are probably interested in:

```
public void WriteStartElement(
    string localName,
    string ns
)
```

where `ns`:

> The namespace URI to associate with the element. If this namespace is already in scope and has an associated prefix, the writer automatically writes that prefix also.